# Using methods in Java for this

Tags: java, methods

I am still very new to Java and I've been struggling with a problem for two days now. I just ask for help with my code. What am I missing or doing incorrectly? Here is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {          
        menu();              
    }  

    public static double getMeters()
    {
        String str;
        double meters;

        // Get meters input from user:
        str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a distance in meters: ");

        // Convert string input to double:
        meters = Double.parseDouble(str);

        // Validate input:
        if (meters <= 0) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Input must be a " +
                    " positive number");     
            getMeters();
            break;
        }    
        else
            return meters;

    }

    public static void menu()
    {
        String choice;
        double meters = getMeters();               

        // Show menu options:
        choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1. Convert to Kilometers \n" + 
                "2. Convert to Inches \n" + "3. Convert to Feet \n" + 
                "4. Quit Program \n" + "\n Enter your choice: ");        

        switch (choice)
        {
            case "1":
                showKilometers(meters);
                menu();
                break;

            case "2":
                showInches(meters);
                menu();
                break;

            case "3":
                showFeet(meters);
                menu();
                break;

            case "4":
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye!");
                System.exit(0);
                break;

            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Invalid   input.");
                menu();
                break;               
        }           
    }

    public static void showKilometers(double meters)
    {
        double kilometers;

        // Convert meters to kilometers:
        kilometers = meters * 0.001;

        // Display result:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, meters + " meters is " +
                kilometers + " kilometers.");       
    }

    public static void showInches(double meters)
    {
        double inches;

        // Convert meters to inches:
        inches = meters * 39.37;

        // Display result:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, meters + " meters is " + 
                inches + " inches.");       
    }

    public static void showFeet(double meters)
    {
        double feet;

        // Convert meters to feet:
        feet = meters * 3.281;

        // Display result:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, meters + " meters is " + 
                feet + " feet.");
    }        
}
```

It keeps saying "missing return statement" in getMeters() method....?
I'm not sure how to fix this to where it can validate input and accept only positive numbers...please help.

This is our first chapter dealing with methods, so I don't know anything advanced or any fancy tricks yet.

Comment: What do you think `break` does? What do you think _missing return statement_ means?

Comment: Why did you feel the need to tell us the full assignment, when all you're asking about is a compile error? Next time, include the full error message and line number.

Comment: Sorry for posting the whole assignment, I was trying to give as much information so everyone would know what I was trying to do.

I'm new to programming and it's my first day on StackOverflow....sorry for any stupid questions now or in the future. :/
 Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct version of the `getMeters()` method is this:

```
public static double getMeters() {
    String str;
    double meters;

    // Get meters input from user:
    str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a distance in meters: ");

    // Convert string input to double:
    meters = Double.parseDouble(str);

    // Validate input:
    if (meters <= 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Input must be a " +
                " positive number");
        return getMeters();
    } else
        return meters;
}
```

I took out the `break`. `break` is for breaking out of `for`, `while`, `do-while` or `switch` statements, so it's not allowed where you put it.

I also changed `getMeters();` to `return getMeters();`. `getMeters()` is a method returning a `double`. You were calling the method but ignoring the returned value. As a consequence you could get to the end of the method without anything being returned. This is not allowed (unless a method has `void` return type).

Comment: Thank you SO much!!! This definitely helped! 
I cannot believe I have been tearing my hair out for 2 days over something so simple! Again, thank you!

Comment: @Jess No worries. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

In your getMeters() method, if the if statement is executed, no double will be returned, because the only return statement is in your else statement. Hope this helps!

BTW, a break statement is invalid inside of an if statement. They are only valid in for loops and while loops, and switch statements.

Comment: Actually, the `break` is invalid. Error message is "break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch".

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Andreas you are right, sorry about that, for some reason I thought that if statement was a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your code for the getMeters() method, you have an if statement that ends with `break;` which will end the function without returning anything. It ought to return an error code or -1.0, just something representing what happened.

```
if (meters <= 0) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Input must be a " + " positive number");     
    getMeters();
    //error code for negative numbers is -1.0
    //note that the return type is (Double) -1.0 rather than (int) -1
    return -1.0;
}
else
    return meters;
```

Also, I would like to address the if condition `meters <= 0`. I bet that a distance of 0 would be valid. If true that would mean that the condition should be `meters < 0`.

Comment: You are right. I should put meters < 0. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In getMeters you can't use break, you should to use "double" as return, remove the statement "break" and then use the "return getMeters();" just below.

Comment: Thank you for your help!